# Does meteor subscribe overwrite old subscriptions?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I was wondering if a meteor subscribe call overwrites previous subscriptions for the same collection?

E.g. If I have pagination and use something like:

Meteor.subscribe('tasks',start,count);

and call:
Meteor.subscribe('tasks',0,10);

and then advance to the next page which subscribes to

Meteor.subscribe('tasks',10,10);

... does meteor keep the first 10 results in memory or does it remove the old content?

My ultimate goal is to provide the user with options to manually subscribe to entire documents for later offline use and I am worried that this practice would interfere with my dynamic subscriptions for online use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you start a subscription with `Meteor.subscribe`, it will remain active until it's manually stopped or the user disconnects (closes the browser, etc.).

So the short answer to your question is: no, the subscriptions will all be active and any duplicate documents will be merged.

This may not be what you want, however, because unless you clean up the subscriptions they will remain on. A common solution to dynamically modifying a subscription's parameters is to use an `autorun`. Here's an example of a template-level `autorun` where we subscribe for `tasks` based on a pair of session variables:

```
Template.tasks.created = function () {
  var self = this;
  this.autorun(function () {
    var start = Session.get('paginationStart');
    var end = Session.get('paginationEnd');
    self.subscribe('tasks', start, end);
  });
};
```

The `autorun` will intelligently start and stop the previous subscription based on its reactive inputs.

For more details on pagination in meteor, I'd recommend reading [this post](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/pagination-problems-meteor/).

Comment: I have a similar problem, I posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42073785/update-subscription-to-meteor-publication Maybe someone can have a look. Thanks