# Update subscription to Meteor publication

Tags: angular, meteor, ionic-framework, publish-subscribe

I am in an **Ionic2** / **Angular2** project using a **Meteor** Database. I have a *Collection* of *Points* and want to show them on a map. Every time the map-view changes, I set a new query with the new *bounds*. This is working quite fine already.

But the collection is already really huge, so I have to reduce the publication as it slows down my app a lot. I want to restrict it also to the bounds of the shown area. So I need to update the subscription every time I send a new query. My code looks like this:

```
MeteorObservable.subscribe('area-points', bounds).subscribe(() => {
  MeteorObservable.autorun().subscribe(() => {
    this.allPoints = <Observable<Point[]>>this.searchArea
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap((bounds: L.LatLngBounds) => {
        //update the bounds of the subscription here
        return Point.find({ /* bounds */ });
      });
  });
});
```

Can someone point me out, how to update the outer subscription?
I found an answer on another post that looks really good, but I don't know how to use it here for my project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34558520/1904790

Thank you very much for helping.